# Questions about ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am learning the continuous dependence on initial values of the solution, when proving the theorem, I encountered a Lemma which goes like this:

If $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $D$, and satisfies the Lipschitz condition for $y$, if the Lipschitz coefficient is $L$, then for any  of the two solutions of the initial problems $\phi(x)$,$\psi(x)$, we have $$|\phi(x)-\psi(x)|\leq |\phi(x_0)-\psi(x_0)|*e^{L|x-x_0|},$$ where $x_0$ is a value of $[a,b]$.

The proof is as follows:

Suppose we have $V(x)=[\phi(x)-\psi(x)]^2$, x$\in[a,b]$, then $V^{'}(x) \leq 2LV(x)$, which means we have **$(V(x)e^{-2Lx})^{'} \leq0$**.

Then, for $x \in [x_0,b]$, we have $V(x)e^{-2Lx} \leq V(x_0)e^{-2Lx_0}$

For $x \in [a,x_0]$, we have $V(x_0)e^{-2Lx_0} \leq V(x)e^{-2Lx}$

Oops, I got the wrong but still confused why. Can anyone help me out, appreciate your helping hands.

Comment: Actually, you have $|V'(x)|\le 2LV(x)$, so that you get a second set of inequalities.

Comment: Sorry, could you please show in details

Comment: You also get $-2LV(x)\le V'(x)$. The calculus remains the same as in the first case that you computed, the useful part of this integration result is now the upper bound on the interval $[a,x_0]$.

Comment: Yes, I did as you said and got the answer, and I find something very intriguing, I can get four inequalities involving $V(x)$ and $V(x_0)$, they had something in common, is it due to the symmetry of the solution?

Comment: You get $-2L\le\frac{V'}{V}\le 2L$, which integrates, using the cases in both directions, to $-2L|x-x_0|\le \ln(V(x)/V(x_0))\le 2L|x-x_0|$. Or in other words, due to the proportionality of the bounding differential inequality, the resulting upper and lower bounds can only evolve exponentially.

Comment: That helps a lot, appreciate it